# Readied actions vs spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, readied-action, cover, kineticist

If a kineticst were to ready an action to use Kinetic Cover when an opponent acts aggressively towards him, how would that interact with a Cleric casting Blindness/Deafness on the kineticist?

Considering Kinetic Cover provides total cover for 1 side of a square, the Cleric would lose sight of the kineticist before casting the spell and thus not be able to complete the action. Would the Cleric lose the spell or would they be able to choose another action?

Answer (score 2):

A [kineticist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/) that takes the special initiative action [ready](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Ready) then picks the action *Use the [utility wild talent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/utility-wild-talents/) kinetic cover special ability to block line of effect between me and that caster* and the trigger *in the midst of that caster casting a spell* would, in fact, gain total [cover](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Cover) from that caster's spell and, therefore, the kineticist (and any other creatures that saw line of sight and line of effect to them blocked by the effect of the special ability kinetic cover) couldn't be the target of, for example, the caster's [*blindness/deafness*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blindness-deafness/) spell.

However, [a caster picks a spell's target when the spell comes into effect](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Casting-Time) (*not*, for example, when the caster *starts* casting the spell). Thus, in the example, a caster could, when he *finishes* the spell, pick any target within range and to which he currently has line of sight and line of effect to be the target of the spell *blindness/deafness*.